# php mssql_connect not working?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to access to my mssql server by php here is the code:

```
<?
mssql_connect($core['localhost'],$core['sa'],$core['mypass']);
mssql_select_db($core['dbone']);
?>
```

This is at the top of my page before `<!DOCTYPE>` Basically when I open my index.php no content is shown  - it's like it can't connect to the mssql? Is there something i have to enable before I can access mssql_connect()?

edit: extension=php_mssql.dll is enabled if this is the right extension?

Comment: Try putting `mssql_connect($core['localhost'],$core['sa'],$core['mypass']) or die('Could not coonect');` and `mssql_select_db($core['dbone']) or die('Database not found');` and see what get's printed out

Comment: not getting anything - just blank page :/

Comment: `or die` is really not good, everyone is using it. [turning on error reporting and displaying those including startup errors](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

It's not "mssql" on both functions change them to "mysql" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging the problem, put this in your index.php and see what gets printed out

```
<?php
$con = mssql_connect($core['localhost'],$core['sa'],$core['mypass']);
if(! $con) { echo 'Could not connect'; }
else { echo 'Connection successful'; }

echo '<br />';

$db = mssql_select_db($core['dbone']);
if (! $db) { echo 'Could not select database'; }
else { echo 'Database selected'; }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
.
.
.
```

Something should get printed out now.

Comment: I think the problem was that after i enabled the mssql extension in php.ini i didn't reset xampp - so after shutting off xampp and attempting to restart it I was unable to start appache? disabling the mssql extension allowed me to start appache again - why can't i start appache with the extension enabled?  @asprin